# Returning garbage numbers and I don't know why

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that reads in numbers from a file into an array, reverse the order of the numbers in the array and then outputs those reversed numbers into a different file.  I was able to get the program to work when I already knew how many numbers were in the file but I am having difficulty when I switch my loop to trying to detect the EOF(End of file).  When I run this code it will print two of the numbers from the file and the rest are garbage values.  Any Help?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int NUMS = 5;

void reverseArray(int number[], int first, int last)
{
   int temp;

   if (first >= last)
   {
      return;
   }

   temp = number[first];
   number[first] = number[last];
   number[last] = temp;

   reverseArray(number, first + 1, last - 1);
}

int main()
{
   //Create file objects
   ifstream inputFile;
   ofstream outputFile;
   string inputName;
   string outputName;

   //Prompt user for file names
   cout << "What is the name of the input file?" << endl;
   getline(cin, inputName);

   cout << "What would you like the output file to be called?" << endl;
   getline(cin, outputName);

   //open user named files
   inputFile.open(inputName);
   outputFile.open(outputName);

   int numsFromFile;

   int numbers[NUMS];

   int fileCount = 0;

   /*
   //read in numbers from a file ********THIS WORKS BUT WHEN I CHANGE IT BELOW IT DOES NOT******
   for (int count = 0; count < NUMS; count++)
   {
   inputFile >> number[count];
   }
    */

   //Try to read numbers in detecting the EOF
   while (inputFile >> numsFromFile)
   {
      inputFile >> numbers[fileCount];
      fileCount++;
   }

   //print numbers to screen
   for (int count = 0; count < fileCount; count++)
   {
      cout << numbers[count] << endl;
   }

   //reverse array
   reverseArray(numbers, 0, 4);

   cout << "Reversed is: " << endl;

   //print reversed array
   for (int count = 0; count < NUMS; count++)
   {
      cout << numbers[count] << endl;
   }

   //output numbers to a file
   for (int count = 0; count < NUMS; count++)
   {
      outputFile << numbers[count] << endl;
   }

   outputFile.close();
   inputFile.close();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you really have to reverse the array? why can't you just output it in reverse order? if you read 1,2,3,4 into the array, then you start from the end, and output 4,3,2,1.

Comment: I am practicing using recursive functions so this is a recursive function that reverses the array

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the lines:

```
while (inputFile >> numsFromFile)
{
   inputFile >> numbers[fileCount];
   fileCount++;
}
```

You end up reading and discarding the 1st number, the 3rd number, the 5th number, etc. Change it to:

```
while (inputFile >> numsFromFile)
{
   numbers[fileCount] = numsFromFile;
   fileCount++;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I actually found it right before you posted but thanks for the quick reply!